# Pug + gulp-file-include

Tags: gulp, pug

Не совсем понимаю, как работает плагин gulp-file-include с pug 
Как можно в файл index.pug передать модуль head.pug c переменной ( @@title ), пример :

head.pug

```
doctype html
html(lang="ru")
head
    meta(charset="UTF-8")
    meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge")
    meta(name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
    title @@title
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.min.css")
body
```

index.pug

```
@@include('module/_head.pug', 'title: Index')
```